# what is the purpose of the BeingDebugged flag in the PEB structure?

Tags: windows, reverse-engineering

What is the purpose of this flag (from the OS side)?
Which functions use this flag except isDebuggerPresent?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

It's effectively the same, but reading the PEB doesn't require a trip through kernel mode.

More explicitly, the `IsDebuggerPresent` API is documented and stable; the PEB structure is not, and could, conceivably, change across versions.

Also, the `IsDebuggerPresent` API (or flag) only checks for user-mode debuggers; kernel debuggers aren't detected via this function.

Why put it in the PEB?  It saves some time, which was more important in early versions of NT.  (There are a bunch of user-mode functions that check this flag before doing some runtime validation, and will break to the debugger if set.)

If you change the PEB field to 0, then `IsDebuggerPresent` will also return 0, although I believe that `CheckRemoteDebuggerPresent` will not.

Comment: @avi.c - hope this expanded answer is more useful.

Answer (score 0):

As you have found the IsDebuggerPresent flag reads this from the PEB. As far as I know the PEB structure is not an official API but IsDebuggerPresent is so you should stick to that layer.

The uses of this method are quite limited if you are after a copy protection to prevent debugging your app. As you have found it is only a flag in your process space. If somebody debugs your application all he needs to do is to zero out the flag in the PEB table and let your app run.

You can raise the level by using the method [CheckRemoteDebuggerPresent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679280%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) where you pass in your own process handle to get an answer. This method goes into the kernel and checks for the existence of a special debug structure which is associated with your process if it is beeing debugged. A user mode process cannot fake this one but you know there are always ways around by simply removing your check ....

Comment: thanks, but this is not what I asked :/

I want to know why ths OS puts this flag in the PEB from the beginning...

as far as I know the OS only uses the debug object (kernel) to check for a debugger. so why he needs this flag (beingDebugged)? just to notify usermode programs? If I set this flag to zero, what happens?